# Understanding `evaluate` Functiion

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci, operator-precedence

The Haskell [docs](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=evaluate) explain the `evaluate` function:

> Forces its argument to be evaluated to weak head normal form when the resultant IO action is executed.

```
Prelude Control.Exception> let xs = [1..100] :: [Int]                                                                   Prelude Control.Exception> :sprint xs
xs = _
Prelude Control.Exception> let ys = evaluate xs
Prelude Control.Exception> :t ys
ys :: IO [Int]
Prelude Control.Exception> ys
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,6Prelu2,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
Prelude Control.Exception> :sprint xs
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,
      24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,
      46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,
      68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,
      90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
Prelude Control.Exception> :sprint ys
ys = _
```

Why is `ys` not in Weak Head Normal Form, i.e. `:sprint ys` does not equal `_ : _`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `ys` value has a type of `IO [Int]`. Now, IO is a abstract type and can be thought of as `RealWorld -> ([Int], RealWorld)` in your case. Now this `IO` value is already in weak head normal form. That's why you see it as `_` when you do `sprint` on it.

> Why is `ys` not in Weak Head Normal Form, i.e. `:sprint ys` does not equal `_ : _`?

`ys` outer term cannot be `_ : _` because it's not a list but it is value of type `IO [Int]`.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what has been said by Sibi, here is a way to see that `evaluate` actually does what the docs say:

```
GHCi> let xs = [1..100] :: [Int]
GHCi> :sprint xs
xs = _
GHCi> let a = evaluate xs >> return ()
GHCi> a
GHCi> :sprint xs
xs = 1 : _
```